# How do I remove firebase analytics from iOS App in store

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I have an app currently in the app store. It uses Firebase analytics framework. I installed this via cocoapods.

eg. `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'` is in my Podfile.

I want to remove analytics completely from my application.

So far I have done the following:

1. Removed all references in code to Firebase.
2. I have removed the `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'` analytics line in my pod file and run `pod install`
3. Once the app update has been loaded and live in the app store I will delete the app in firebase and delete the firebase project.

   [image]

The app builds and complies fine, however I am curious if there are other steps I need to take in order to insure the analytics framework is removed.

Thanks!

Comment: No these are all the steps needed to remove this framework from your application. The only way it possibly could be still there if another Firebase library somehow encapsulated the Firebase-Analytics framework (Or needed it as a dependency somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you remove the Firebase plugin from your app (here from `pod`), analytics has no way to communicate with Firebase anymore, so it is effectively removed.

No, there are no more extra steps required.